# Excel cell formatting date representation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am having a bit of trouble in doing the below conversion. Could I write an excel formula that would give me this output? I tried using the SUBSTITUTE formula, the output however comes as a number instead of a string.

Represent 10-03-2016 14:00 as 2016.03.10 14:00

Apologies if this is too simple a question. I don't have much experience in writing excel forumlae.

Thanks,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy.dd.mm hh:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a genuis! Thanks

Comment: Hey Gilgamesh, quick question- Using the above the date is placed before months. Any solution to fix it?

Comment: @abhaytaneja: Because that's the result you wanted. If you want the result to be `2016.10.03 14:00` then just change the formula to `=TEXT("yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm")`.